# how to get the area of a region using matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I want to plot some equations and inequalities like x>=50, y>=0,4x-5y>=8,x=40,x=60,y=25, y=45 in matlab and want to get the area produced by intersecting these equations and inequalities. Is it possible using matlab? If yes can someone provide me some manual? If not, is there some other software that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Integrals would work for your purposes, provided you know the points at which the curves intersect (something Matlab is also able to compute). [Take a look at the documentation on the integral function.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html)

> `q = integral(fun,xmin,xmax)` approximates the integral of function `fun`
>   from `xmin` to `xmax` using global adaptive quadrature and default error
>   tolerances.

**EDIT:** As an additional resource, take a look at the code provided by user [Grzegorz Konz on the Mathworks blog](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15653-evaluating-the-area-between-two-curves).

**EDIT #2:** I'm not familiar with any Matlab functions that'll take a vector of functions and return the points of intersection (if any) between *all* the curves. Users have produced functions that [return the set of intersection points between two curves](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections). You could run this function for each pair of equations in your list and use a function like [polyarea](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyarea.html) to compute the area of the enclosed region *if* the curves are all straight lines.

Comment: I have seen those two documents. But problem is that i don't know which line will be intersecting some other line. Because these equalities and inequalities will be generated automatically. I found (http://www.mathworks.in/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/linopt-plot_data.html) that can plot the area. But there it is mentioned (This functionality does not run in MATLAB).

Comment: Can anything be assumed about the equalities and inequalities that are generated, then? Is it conceivable, for example, that some of the inequalities are quadratic? There are functions like `polyarea` that calculate the area of a polygon enclosed between points, but it's not immediately clear that you can assume that in your problem.